# Angular Observable not doing the put call

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on my first Angular app, but am having a problem going an `http.put` call.  Here is the function I call:

```
updateUser(columns, values) : Observable<boolean> | boolean { 
  const headers: Headers = new Headers(); // Need to set content type
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authenticationService.token}`);
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });console.log('test service');
  return this.http.put(`${API_URL}users/${this.authenticationService.userId}`, JSON.stringify({ columns: columns, values: values }) , options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('test service1');return Observable.of(true);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('test service2');return Observable.of(false);
    });
```

When I call the function `test service` prints to the console, but `test service1` and `test service2` never print out.  I checked my express backend and chrome dev tools and the app is never making the put call to the backend.  There are no errors in the console either.  So I am missing something, but can't figure it out.

Thank you for any help

**Edit:** I'm wondering if the issue is because I am just calling this function in another function:

```
saveColumns(){
  this.userService.updateUser('home_columns',this.columns_show);
  localStorage.setItem('columns_show', JSON.stringify(this.columns_show) );
}
```

for http.get functions, I typically do something like this:

```
loadStudents(page: number, grade = []) {
if (grade.length != 0){
  this.student_query_filter = { key:'grade_level',value:grade.join('||') };
} else {
  this.student_query_filter = {};
}

this.studentService.getStudentsCount([{ key: 'last_name', value: this.student_search_filter },this.student_query_filter])
.subscribe(
   total => this.total = total, //Assign returned student count to local property
   err => { console.log(err); });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to pass the data as an object instead of with `JSON.stringify`.
- You want to return the result from map, not another Observable. If you did want to return a different observable you should change `map` to `switchMap`.
- The signature should be `Observable<boolean>` as that is what you are returning.

Be sure to check the developer console in your browser to see if the request is being sent and what the response is. It might be something simple like putting together the URL incorrectly (missing a `/` for example)

```
updateUser(columns, values) : Observable<boolean>  {
  const headers: Headers = new Headers(); // Need to set content type
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authenticationService.token}`);
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  console.log('test service, sending to: ' + `${API_URL}users/${this.authenticationService.userId}`);

  return this.http.put(`${API_URL}users/${this.authenticationService.userId}`, { columns: columns, values: values }, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('test service1');
        return true;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('test service2');
        return false;
    }); 
}
```

---

#### Edit

If your caller is not going to do anything with the result and you do not care what that result is then do not return an Observable at all. Change the return signature to `void` and execute a `subscribe` after the call to log the result.

```
this.http.put(`${API_URL}users/${this.authenticationService.userId}`, { columns: columns, values: values }, options)
    .subscribe((response: Response) => {
        console.log('test service1'); }
    , e => {
        console.log('test service2');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  It seems to do the same thing still though.  When I call the function, the console just shows: `test service, sending to: http://10.1.7.12:3000/api/users/58d2ae2c801c9f4bd4626ba7` and when I check the developer tools, it shows no request to the URL.  So it's getting into that function but not making the call for some reason

Comment: @MrV - 1) I updated the `console.log` call to include the url, can you verify that it puts out the url you are expecting? 2) If that checks out please verify that `this.http` is defined, it could be that it was not injected correctly. Add `console.log('Http defined = ' + !!this.http);` before your call.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Here is the output:
`Http defined = true`
`test service, sending to: http://10.1.7.12:3000/api/users/58d2ae2c801c9f4bd4626ba7`

Comment: @MrV - one more thing I noticed (notice the options): `this.http.put(`${API_URL}users/${this.authenticationService.userId}`, { columns: columns, values: values }, { headers: headers })`

Comment: @MrV - finally what happens when you step through your code with the debugger, does it complete this step and return the Observable to the caller?

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is the way I am calling the function.  For my `http.get` calls I'm using subscribe, but for this I am just calling `this.userService.updateUser('home_columns',this.columns_show);`  I'll edit my post to better show what I referring to

Comment: @MrV - If the caller does not care about the result (only that it was called) the service does not have to return an observable. It could do the `subscribe` call in the method itself, just remove the map/catch and turn `map` into `subscribe` and your done.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you @Igor.